# type issue undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, undefined, undefined-function

I've got an issue that I just don't understand as I'm a newbie.  I'm running a jquery plugin on a wordpress site and since upgrading wordpress to the latest version, the jquery plugin doesn't work (http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com).

I get the following error whenever the slider tries to fire:
`type issue 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'c_old.last()')`

Can anyone take a look, I've tried upgrading jquery and the plugin to the latest and still the same issue occurs.

Here's the site is anyone would like to help me out: http://asccs.qc.ca

It's on the home page, #lesArticles

worse part is, I got it to work locally but not on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you include jQuery 1.9.1 within your head, your jQuery ends up being jQuery 1.2.6 because another included script overwrites your jQuery.
To prove that, type the following in the console:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

It will respond with "1.2.6".
You see the error because the last() function on a jQuery object is not defined in jQuery version 1.2.6.

To resolve the issue, try including

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.9.1">
```

***right before*** you include

```
<script src="http://asccs.qc.ca/wp-content/themes/asccs/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0.js">
```

Comment: thank you very much, that did the trick, would you know off hand how to find out which plugin or script is loading 1.2.6?  Thanks again

Comment: it might be cforms.js, but I'm not sure because it's minimized. There is also a noconflict() call right after it got included.